# Updating Year in One Column Based on Month of Another Column that accounts for New Year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have created this DataFrame:

```
  agency coupon vintage Cbal       Month       CPR          year  month Month_Predicted_DT
0   FHLG    1.5 2021    70.090310   November    5.418937    2022    11  2022-11-01
1   FHLG    1.5 2021    70.090310   December    5.549916    2022    12  2022-12-01
2   FHLG    1.5 2021    70.090310   January     5.238943    2022    1   2022-01-01
3   FHLG    1.5 2020    52.414637   November    5.514456    2022    11  2022-11-01
4   FHLG    1.5 2020    52.414637   December    5.550490    2022    12  2022-12-01
5   FHLG    1.5 2020    52.414637   January 5.182304        2022    1   2022-01-01
```

Created from this original df:

```
  agency  coupon year   Cbal        November    December    January
0   FHLG    1.5 2021    70.090310   5.418937    5.549916    5.238943
1   FHLG    1.5 2020    52.414637   5.514456    5.550490    5.182304
2   FHLG    2.0 2022    44.598755   3.346706    3.715995    3.902644
3   FHLG    2.0 2021    472.209165  5.802857    5.899596    5.627774
4   FHLG    2.0 2020    269.761452  7.090993    7.091404    6.567561
```

Using this code:

```
citi = pd.read_excel("Downloads/CITI_2022_05_22(5_22).xlsx")

#Extracting just the relevant months (M, M+1, M+2)
M = citi.columns[-6]
M_1 = citi.columns[-4]
M_2 = citi.columns[-2]

#Extracting just the relevant columns
cols = ['agency-term','coupon','year','Cbal',M,M_1,M_2]
citi = citi[cols]
todays_date = date.today()
current_year = todays_date.year
citi_new['year'] = current_year
citi_new['month'] = pd.to_datetime(citi_new.Month, format="%B").dt.month
citi_new['Month_Predicted_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(citi_new[['year', 'month']].assign(DAY=1))
citi_new = citi.set_index(cols[0:4]).stack().reset_index()
citi_new.rename(columns={"level_4": "Month", 0 : "CPR", "year" : "vintage"}, inplace = True)
```

For reference `M` is the current month, and `M_1` and `M_2` are month+1 and month+2.

My main question is that my solution for creating the `'Month_Predicted_DT` column only works if the months in question do not overlap with the new year, so if `M  == November` or `M == December`, then the year in `Month_Predicted_DT` is not correct for January and/or February. For example, `Month_Predicted_DT` for January rows should be `2023-01-01` not `2022`. The same would be true if `M` was December, then I would want rows for Jan. and Feb. to be `2023-01-01` and `2023-02-01`, respectively.

I have tried to come up with a workaround using `df.iterrows` or `np.where` but just can't really get a working solution.

Comment: How do you decide which months correspond to the current year and which months are for the next year?

Comment: Good question. The files come in monthly and contain the current months and two months out, so the current month is the the "lowest" one (i.e. for this file: November). Therefore, January would be for the next year. If the current month is December, then January and February would be the next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding 12 months to dates that are over two months out:

```
#get first day of the current month
start = pd.Timestamp.today().normalize().replace(day=1)

#convert month column to timestamps
dates = pd.to_datetime(df["Month"]+f"{start.year}", format="%B%Y")

#offset the year if the date is not in the next 3 months
df["Month_Predicted_DT"] = dates.where(dates>=start,dates+pd.DateOffset(months=12))
```

Comment: Great! This worked. It turns out we also need to include the previous one and two months (M-1 and M-2) from the current month. Is there a modification you can make to your solution to account for that? As it is now, previous months are showing as `2023` instead of this year. Thanks!

Comment: Change the first line to `start = (pd.Timestamp.today()-pd.DateOffset(months=1)).normalize().replace(day=1)`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will implement that change and let you know if there are any issues. Oh also is there a way to make it the last of the month instead of the first?

Comment: Would that be via the `day=1` parameter? I'm wondering how to code it in since the last day of the month is different for each month.

Comment: You could DateOffset by one day. `start - pd.DateOffset(days=1)`. Also, please do not ask any more follow-up questions in the comments. New question, new post.